# Why does the jQuery .submit() event not appear to trigger on iPads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, submit

I'm currently running into an issue where I have a form that needs to have its default submit behavior interrupted and replaced with an Ajax call. My current setup appears to work for all other desktop and mobile devices (including iPhones!), but consistently fails for iPads. Specifically, jQuery's `.submit()` doesn't appear to trigger at all. Placing an `alert()` call between the `event.preventDefault();` and `return false;` statements seems to indicate that the code block is never reached. I've also tried switching the submit button to a normal button and submitting on click, and switching to the `on('submit', functon(){...});` syntax to no avail.

Any solutions or ideas as to possible causes?

HTML structure:

```
<form id="targetForm" action="">
    <!--inputs go here-->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Javascript structure:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#targetForm').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('test');
            //Ajax call goes here
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: [Works just fine on my iPad](http://output.jsbin.com/cobetimahu)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Would you mind providing software versions? I'd very much appreciate the opportunity to compare.

Comment: iOS 10.3.3.....

Comment: ...and 11.0.1..

Comment: It seems that despite having been updated just today, the iPad I'm testing on is 9.3.5.

Comment: I have an old iPad still on 9.3.5 and just tested T.J. Crowder's example code from the jsbin link, it works for me. Is their example failing for you? If not, could there be something else in your page that's binding to the submit event or removing your event listener?

Comment: I suspect that it could be an issue with an outdated version of jQuery that doesn't play well with iPads. I'll have to test this on Monday.

Comment: I've taken another look at this problem and it seems that even when lowering the jQuery version in the jsbin example, it ends up working perfectly. I sat there messing with it for a while and couldn't get it to fail. Going back to my own code, even updating jQuery didn't work. So in all likelihood, this is a software conflict with some other JS library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem existed in an unrelated function defined outside of the `$(document).ready()` event where a variable declaration was not terminated by a semicolon and lacked the `var` keyword. It threw no errors on any other devices, but caused the entire external JS file to fail to execute.

Edit, more information: It appears to be an issue with whatever JS engine is being used on iPads. For some reason, any small technically incorrect syntax issue (it even fails if you use default parameter values for some reason!) anywhere in your script file will prevent any of the JS from running. Their engine seems to be incredibly strict about very precisely meeting very specific syntax standards and punishes you severely with failing errors if you don't perfectly conform to them.

In short: My login issue is resolved.